# Python, Selenium + stale element reference

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to go on a webpage, 
save a set of links of the page I would like to click on, and then
I would like to click on each of the link if a for loop (going back and forth on the page. Here is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Applications/chromedriver')
driver.get("webpage link") #insert link to webpage
list_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'activities')]")


for link in list_links:
    print(link)
    link.click()
    driver.goback()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
driver.quit()
```

However, the first time I go back to the homepage I get the error message:

```
StaleElementReferenceException: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.
```

Can anyone help me to understand why? Suggest a solution?
Thank you. much appreciated.

Comment: Its simple, you trying to save the elements of an html(links) which cannot be referenced anymore by the code(the loop logic), thats why it throws this error. Most of all those are selenium objects you trying to save which you should not do. It should be that you save the exact value of the link in an array and then loop them.

Comment: thanks Hassan. Have you got any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Just save the link(exact hyper link value) in an array to use them later in the loop.

Comment: @Reti43, my bad ! Ill post it :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `list_links` works only on page where it was defined. After you made first click on link DOM re-created and references to elements of `list_links` becomes invalid. You can apply below solution:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10) # seconds
list_links = [link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[contains(@href,'activities')]")]

for link in list_links:
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)
    driver.goback()
driver.quit()
```

P.S. I assume that `goback()` is your custom method that was defined already as there is no such method in Selenium built-ins, but just `back()`

P.P.S. Note that you can call `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` only once in your code and it will be applicable for all next `find_element...()` calls

Comment: Thanks very much Andersson. I understood the mistake. Also, I believe that get(link) will click on the link and in conjunction with back() it will allow me to go back and forth. I'll do some more reading on this. But thanks very much!!

Comment: Not exactly. `get(link)` just allows you to navigate to the same URL as if you click on link. And `back()` navigates you back to previous page

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, you trying to save the elements of an html(links) which cannot be referenced anymore by the code(the loop logic), thats why it throws this error. Most of all those are selenium objects you trying to save which you should not do. It should be that you save the exact value of the link in an array and then loop them.